# How to integrate tumblr in android?

Tags: android

I wanna login by tumblr in my android apps same as facebook and google login.Tell me complete process of tumblr integration and get complete information about user. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at tumblr oauth documentation at https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2